# Showing 'favorite' questions first in search result

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

I often favorite questions I know I'm going to ask myself in two weeks. Can I make it appear at the top of search results when I look for something that matches the 'favorite' question?

Answer (score 3):

While it doesn't seem correct to arbitrarily throw a favorited question to the top regardless of relevance, I think it would be a good idea to use 'favorite' status as an indication of relevance, improving its placement on the list (all the way to the top if it was already pretty relevant).

I'm just picturing people who have many favorites searching and getting 20 favorites that match one of 5 words, pushing down relevant results that match all 5.

Comment: Or something like a link on top of search results (just like Google's "did you mean") which would say: "You've got favorite questions that partially match your query. Would you like to see them?". That'd be perfect for me, without altering search result ranking.

Comment: That's a completely different (and just as valid) answer. You should make it an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A link on top of search results (just like Google's *Did you mean?*) which would say *You've got favorite questions that partially match your query. Would you like to see them?* could be a solution which wouldn't alter search result ranking.